# eat almost nothing but keep metabolism awake

Tags: weight-loss

I am 173cm 67kg male, eating less and fast-walking 5 km(about an hour) everyday but doesn't seems to losing any fat. so should I double walking or decrease what I eat(which is about nothing)? If I decrease my food intake I am afraid to make my metabolism in fasting mode.

(also I stopped taking any caffeine for unrelated health care)

Its been a month I do this,
I checked what I am eating is approximately;

morning 500 calories

lunch 750 calories

dinner 500 calories (sometimes I don't eat dinner, some nuts or fruits)

I eat this in the morning http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simit, 1 egg omelet, some cheese and juice.

lunch kids burger menu (65 gr. meat) or popeyes fried chicken menu (I eat half of it) with a sprite or water.

and dinner I eat this http://www.guneytantuni.com/_img/slide_1.png (meat wrap) with water.

Comment: Give us some concrete information. How many calories are you consuming each day? What foods are you eating? How long have you been doing this?

Comment: @John Kugelman I added some more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

67kg at 173cm gives you a BMI of 22, which is right in the "normal" range.

**So direct weight loss is probably not in your best interest.** What you more than likely want is to reduce your body fat percentage, which can be done either by losing body fat, increasing muscle mass, or some combination of both.

At your weight, focus on introducing some form of weight training to increase your muscle mass, either with weights, such as barbell, dumbell or kettlebell training, or with bodyweight training, such as push-ups, pull ups, or bodyweight squats.

**Look at introducing exercises to improve your muscle mass**, and it will reduce your body fat percentage, which will likely meet your goals of *looking* and *feeling* fitter.

Comment: I do BB once a week and I drink protein shake after sessions, mostly incline/normal bench press (40-50 kg), squats (50kg), and some dumbell work. but I have "big stomach syndrome". so I decided to drop all fat first (like under %5) after train some stomach vacuums to make it flat.

Comment: @Mert: Hope you don't mind if I pitch in. A frequency of once a week is _way_ too low. For beginners, three times a week is advised. This higher frequency stimulates the muscles more often and leads to more strength and growth (also increases calories burned). Recovery shouldn't be an issue, either, until you get much stronger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to fat at 67kg/173cm, that means you will have very little muscle mass. Startving yourself, if you are not loosing fat, may actually be making it worse. You may be eating the very little muscle mass you have left.

Instead of trying to loose weight, its probably wiser to instead start a strength-first program and get your FFBM to a level more suitable for your stature. Stop the low intensity cardio, stop starving yourself, pick up strength training and eat. Don't even consider under eating, at least not just yet. Do try to go relatively low-carb so you don't gain to much fat while eating sufficient to gain muscle mass.

More muscle mass will help increase your BMR and will give you a more balanced body composition with a lower body fat 'percentage'.Ones you have a FFBM of something like 55 kg to 65 kg (pick a gym with a body composition measuring device) you might choose to start working on your body fat mass second. That is, you may try to loose fat by doing cardio and low caloric dieting and things like that. But than, if your tape measure agrees, you may not even have to.